# mod_rewrite END flag not working in httpd 2.4

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

The `END` flag for mod_rewrite in Apache 2.4 does not appear to be working correctly. I have a directory named `test` with a file `test.html`. I have placed an `.htaccess` file in the directory with the following content

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^test$ test.html [NC,QSA,END]
RewriteRule ^$ test.html  [NC,QSA,END]
```

Here is the rewrite log for the request http://localhost.dev/test/

```
[...] 10.0.2.2 - - [localhost.dev/sid#2532c00][rid#2a56d60/initial] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/vhosts/test/ -> 
[...] 10.0.2.2 - - [localhost.dev/sid#2532c00][rid#2a56d60/initial] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/test/] applying pattern '^test$' to uri ''
[...] 10.0.2.2 - - [localhost.dev/sid#2532c00][rid#2a56d60/initial] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/vhosts/test/ -> 
[...] 10.0.2.2 - - [localhost.dev/sid#2532c00][rid#2a56d60/initial] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/test/] applying pattern '^$' to uri ''
[...] 10.0.2.2 - - [localhost.dev/sid#2532c00][rid#2a56d60/initial] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/test/] rewrite '' -> 'test.html'
[...] 10.0.2.2 - - [localhost.dev/sid#2532c00][rid#2a56d60/initial] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/test/] add per-dir prefix: test.html -> /var/www/vhosts/test/test.html
[...] 10.0.2.2 - - [localhost.dev/sid#2532c00][rid#2a56d60/initial] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/test/] strip document_root prefix: /var/www/vhosts/test/test.html -> /test/test.html
[...] 10.0.2.2 - - [localhost.dev/sid#2532c00][rid#2a56d60/initial] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/test/] internal redirect with /test/test.html [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[...] 10.0.2.2 - - [localhost.dev/sid#2532c00][rid#2a44060/subreq] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/vhosts/test/index.php -> index.php
[...] 10.0.2.2 - - [localhost.dev/sid#2532c00][rid#2a44060/subreq] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/test/] applying pattern '^test$' to uri 'index.php'
[...] 10.0.2.2 - - [localhost.dev/sid#2532c00][rid#2a44060/subreq] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/vhosts/test/index.php -> index.php
[...] 10.0.2.2 - - [localhost.dev/sid#2532c00][rid#2a44060/subreq] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/test/] applying pattern '^$' to uri 'index.php'
[...] 10.0.2.2 - - [localhost.dev/sid#2532c00][rid#2a44060/subreq] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/test/] pass through /var/www/vhosts/test/index.php
[...] 10.0.2.2 - - [localhost.dev/sid#2532c00][rid#2a44060/subreq] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/vhosts/test/index.html -> index.html
[...] 10.0.2.2 - - [localhost.dev/sid#2532c00][rid#2a44060/subreq] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/test/] applying pattern '^test$' to uri 'index.html'
[...] 10.0.2.2 - - [localhost.dev/sid#2532c00][rid#2a44060/subreq] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/vhosts/test/index.html -> index.html
[...] 10.0.2.2 - - [localhost.dev/sid#2532c00][rid#2a44060/subreq] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/test/] applying pattern '^$' to uri 'index.html'
[...] 10.0.2.2 - - [localhost.dev/sid#2532c00][rid#2a44060/subreq] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/test/] pass through /var/www/vhosts/test/index.html
```

Why is mod_rewrite making sub requests for directory index files `index.html` and `index.php`, when the second rule matches the request?

Request for http://localhost.dev/test/test works without any sub request, as expected

```
[...] 10.0.2.2 - - [localhost.dev/sid#2532c00][rid#2a58b20/initial] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/vhosts/test/test -> test
[...] 10.0.2.2 - - [localhost.dev/sid#2532c00][rid#2a58b20/initial] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/test/] applying pattern '^test$' to uri 'test'
[...] 10.0.2.2 - - [localhost.dev/sid#2532c00][rid#2a58b20/initial] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/test/] rewrite 'test' -> 'test.html'
[...] 10.0.2.2 - - [localhost.dev/sid#2532c00][rid#2a58b20/initial] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/test/] add per-dir prefix: test.html -> /var/www/vhosts/test/test.html
[...] 10.0.2.2 - - [localhost.dev/sid#2532c00][rid#2a58b20/initial] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/test/] strip document_root prefix: /var/www/vhosts/test/test.html -> /test/test.html
[...] 10.0.2.2 - - [localhost.dev/sid#2532c00][rid#2a58b20/initial] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/test/] internal redirect with /test/test.html [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

I have tried using `L` and `END` flags, independently and together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hit the same problem on Apache 2.4.7 on Ubuntu and reported a bug to Apache which was confirmed and is fixed in 2.4.9, see [here](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56434). For Ubuntu, there is an updated PPA [here](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/apache2) for easy upgrade. If upgrading is not possible or you don't want to compile the sources, you can use Joyce's workaround above, or the one I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23174792/apache-2-4-rewrite-rule-for-root-matches-but-is-ignored-subreq-for-index-file) which uses only RewriteCond and RewriteRule.

Answer (score 2):

It appears mod_dir does not respect the END flag set by mod_rewrite. For anyone else who is experiencing this, I was able to work around the problem with the following

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ /test/home.php  [NC,QSA,END,E=IS_DIR_INDEX:1]
FallbackResource /test/fallback.php

<If "env('IS_DIR_INDEX') == 1">
    SetHandler default_handler
</If>
```